# URL Path incorrect with Magento Rest API

Tags: category, rest-api, category-tree

I am using Python to access Magento 2 Rest API categories.

The url that I am using is this:

https:///rest/<store_code>/V1/categories/15647

The URL Path that is being returned is this:

footwear/weights/hiking-boots-shoes

however the correct path is:

footwear/men/hiking-boots-shoes

Most of the url_path for the categories are coming back correctly. But I estimate at least 15% error rate in the url_path

Comment: Is "hiking boots shoes" added to both Men and Weights categories?

Comment: Weights does not exist as a category

Comment: All of the erroneous url_path that I am extracting from Magento Rest API are giving me a 404 error because they do not exist

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to avoid doing backend development for this issue and have thus come up with a solution to create the field url_path by using the url_key, parent_id and level.

It is a workaround for a field that should be working in Magento, but I would rather not waste company ressources trying to correct this error when I can build the url_path myself.

Thanks